# yahoo email address in query string cause query redirect to yahoo web site

Tags: api, request, yahoo

When I query my api service with yahoo email address in query string, the whole request redirect to yahoo website. 
please check this url in your browser :

```
stackoverflow.com/?var="a@yahoo.com"&x="100"
```